# version control with Zerobrane

Tags: version-control, zerobrane

I'm using Zerobrane and Corona SDK for my Lua project and would like to save my work and use version control to revert easily to an older version if necessary.

I haven't found any way to do that with Zerobrane and noting mentioned in the documentation.

Do you have any recommendation for version control using these tools? I'm also open to any online service (Github or similar....)

The simpler, the better !

Answer (score 0):

There is an experimental version control module that supports svn (https://github.com/Minebea-Intec/zbssvn), but no other version control integration that I'm aware of. I'm using git from the command line and the IDE will recognize that the file on disk has been updated and will reload it in the editor (if it's already open).